# Var scope on the same line

Tags: javascript, optimization

Is there a better way I can code this? It's old code and I'm not sure makes sense today. JSLint gives me a lot of errors too. I don't have experience with JavaScript and I would like to optimize this snippet.

Any suggestion? Maybe I can achieve better code with JQuery?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// <![CDATA[
    var jump_page = '{LA_JUMP_PAGE}:',
    var on_page = '{ON_PAGE}';
    var per_page = '{PER_PAGE}';
    var base_url = '{A_BASE_URL}';
    var style_cookie = 'phpBBstyle';
    var style_cookie_settings = '{A_COOKIE_SETTINGS}';
    var onload_functions = new Array();
    var onunload_functions = new Array();

    /**
    * Find a member
    */
    function find_username(url)
    {
        popup(url, 760, 570, '_usersearch');
        return false;
    }

    /**
    * New function for handling multiple calls to window.onload and window.unload by pentapenguin
    */
    window.onload = function()
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < onload_functions.length; i++)
        {
            eval(onload_functions[i]);
        }
    };

    window.onunload = function()
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < onunload_functions.length; i++)
        {
            eval(onunload_functions[i]);
        }
    };

// ]]>
</script>
```

This is how an handler is called for example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// <![CDATA[
    /**
    * Change language
    */
    function change_language(lang_iso)
    {
        document.forms['register'].change_lang.value = lang_iso;
        document.forms['register'].submit.click();
    }

    <!-- IF CAPTCHA_TEMPLATE and S_CONFIRM_REFRESH -->
    onload_functions.push('apply_onkeypress_event()');
    <!-- ENDIF -->

// ]]>
</script>
```

Comment: @syb0rg A JSLint "error" does not necessarily mean that the code is broken.

Comment: @200_success It failed initially at 2%, so I assumed it was broken code.  Close vote retracted.

Comment: jslint probably doesn't like the comma at the end of the first line, should be a semicolon, or you should setup all the vars with a single var statement and commas in between declarations.

Comment: Also, Egyptian brackets are considered better practice in javascript.

Answer (score 8):

The [modern way](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-eventgroupings-htmlevents) to attach `onLoad` and `onUnload` handlers is to use `window.addEventListener('load', onloadFunction)` and `window.addEventListener('unload', onunloadFunction)`.  Unlike `window.onload`, you can attach multiple handlers, saving you the work of writing your own support for multiple handlers.

Unfortunately, Internet Explorer only added support for `addEventListener()` in IE 9.  Therefore, you'll probably need a [shim](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6927800/1157100).  That would be a common shim that supports a standard interface, rather than your own hack, so I would still consider it an improvement.

Comment: Thanks 200_success, How can I merge my code above with your solution? I dont want to use shim for now.

Comment: @user2513846 that depends on why you don't want to use a shim?

Comment: I just dont want to add extra scripts I gues and keep it as simple as possible.

Comment: The shim that I linked to is just one function, and it replaces two of your functions. If anything, it makes your code simpler!

Comment: well sounds good then lol . sorry I just dont have enough knoledge in JS. What code should  I use to replace my code above?

Answer (score 6):

JSLint is probably complaining about your use of `eval()`, and I would be wary too.  [Don't use `eval` needlessly.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Don.27t_use_eval.21) You didn't show your onload/onunload handlers, but you should write them as functions rather than strings to be evaluated.

Bad:

```
window.onload = function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < onload_functions.length; i++) {
        eval(onload_functions[i]);
    }
};

onload_functions.push('apply_onkeypress_event()');
```

Better:

```
window.onload = function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < onload_functions.length; i++) {
        onload_functions[i]();
    }
};

onload_functions.push(apply_onkeypress_event);
```

Comment: this would be an example of the handler:
    <script type="text/javascript">
    // <![CDATA[
 /**
 * Change language
 */
 function change_language(lang_iso)
 {
        document.forms['register'].change_lang.value = lang_iso;
  document.forms['register'].submit.click();
 }

 <!-- IF CAPTCHA_TEMPLATE and S_CONFIRM_REFRESH -->
 onload_functions.push('apply_onkeypress_event()');
 <!-- ENDIF -->

    // ]]>
    </script>

Comment: sorry not sure why it's not coded

Comment: Because it is in a comment, edit the question instead!